# Weird syntax errors in header file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a header file containing an interface with properties and methods (let's call it E.h), and Xcode notifies me about syntax errors inside this header field, which make no sense because E.h doesn't contain any error.
These errors appear only under certain conditions:

E.h is already included in A.h, and there is no error.

When E.h is not included in B.m, there is no errors and it compiles fine, but if I include it in B.m, errors show up. (B.m doen't use any code from E.h)

Additional information: B.m includes B.h and then E.h .

I didn't find relevant to include source code because it represents thousands of lines and I won't ask you to analyze this.
I jus need some hints for what could be the cause and where to start searching.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you include the lines showing errors, and say what the errors are

Comment: Just a stupid guess, but did you try retyping the line of code that shows errors? You might've copied and pasted it from a site that had some encoding problems so it may look like a quote but it's not.

Comment: I get missing semi colons errors inside properties declarations and missing @end, (which make no sense )

Comment: @theamateurprogrammer no, nothing copy pasted !

Comment: I forget the `;` at the end of classes all the time and the error gets carried through to the including file. If the code directly after the include appears to do something legal with the class then no errors show up. Might be worth looking for missing `#endif`s etc too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the "Show Preprocess" option in Xcode, I found that the property in E.h named `@property (retain) NSString *MY_STRING;` was replaced with `@property (retain) NSString *@"My String"`. It appeared that there was a `define MY_STRING @"My String"` included in a different header file itself included in B.h, itself included in B.m before E.h .Hard to spot ! Lesson of the day : never write your variables in upper case.

Answer (score -1):

In C++ this works, maybe will help you:

in file E.h

```
#ifndef __ECLASS__
#define __ECLASS__

<here original declarations from E.h>

#endif
```

Comment: That's not necessary in Objective-C, since `#import` checks to see if a file has already been included